# Entry/Exit Trace for Ruby - can this be made better?

Tags: c++, ruby, logging

When writing a logging package for C++, I also provided a means for the programmer to have an easy way to do a logging of function entry and exit. Usage example:

```
// C++
int myfunc(int status) {
  FTRACE("status=",status)
  ...
}
```

This generated a log message similar to

```
ENTRY myfunc status=45
...
EXIT myfunc
```

The implementation used C++ macros (to get at the function name) and created a special trace object on the stack, and the destructor would then produce the EXIT message.

I was wondering whether I could do something similar in Ruby.

Here is what I implemented (but I'm not entirely happy with it):

```
def ftrace(*args)
    caller()[0] =~ /`(.+)'/
    calling_method = $1 # || '???'
    puts "ENTRY #{calling_method} #{args.join(' ')}"
    begin
      yield(*args) if block_given?
    rescue Exception => e
      puts "EXIT #{calling_method} by exception"
      raise e
    end
    puts "EXIT #{calling_method}"
end
```

(Of course in a real application, I would not use 'puts' for logging, but invoke my logging package).

This code would be used like this:

```
def myfunc(foo,bar,baz)
    ftrace("foo =",foo) {
      ...
    }
end
```

This works, but the need of an additional block is ugly. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Take a look at [`set_trace_func`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Kernel.html#method-i-set_trace_func) / [`TracePoint`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/TracePoint.html)

Comment: I don't think this would help in my case. The trace handler, which is set up by set_trace_func, will be entered right at the entry point of my function. At this point, I don't have yet the information, whether this function should be traced or not, and also not the information, which data should be printed in the trace.